# Emacs -- test to determine what type of hook is running

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a test to determine what type of hook is running -- e.g., `window-configuration-change-hook`?

For example, I have a function that contains conditions used determine whether it should be run -- it is used in conjunction with `post-command-hook`.  I would like to use the same function for the `window-configuration-change-hook`, without triggering the first set of conditions:

```
(when

  (or

    (and
      (not window-configuration-change-hook) ;; illustrative example only
      (memq this-command this-last-command-inclusions)
      (not multiple-cursors-mode))

     window-configuration-change-hook) ;; illustrative example only

   . . .
```

Comment: As Tobias points out, there's no sensible way to test this. So while it might be a handy feature suggestion, at present you should simply split your function in two, and add the appropriate function to the appropriate hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no standardized method to determine which hook is running.

If you want to use `advice` or something like that to store this information you have to be aware that hooks can run within hooks. See the following example.
That means you need a stack-like structure to store that information.

EDIT: The example includes now a `hook-stack` storing the currently running hooks.
Note, I do not recommend to use this method since it is quite critical and does not work in all cases. Better, advice the mode/function or whatever what you want to identify.

```lisp
(defvar hook-stack nil)

(defadvice run-hooks (around register-hooks activate)
  "Store current hook into `hook-stack'."
  (let ((hooks (ad-get-args 0)))
    (loop for h in hooks do
      (unwind-protect
          (progn
        (push h hook-stack)
        (ad-set-args 0 (list h))
        ad-do-it))
      (pop hook-stack)
      )))

(ad-remove-advice 'run-hooks 'around 'register-hooks)

(setq hooks1 nil)
(setq hooks2 nil)

(add-hook 'hooks1 (lambda () (message "Running hooks1, hook-stack: %S" hook-stack)))

(add-hook 'hooks2 (lambda () (message "Running hooks2") (run-hooks 'hooks1)
            (message "Finishing hooks2, hook-stack: %S" hook-stack)))

(run-hooks 'hooks2)
```

Note: This does not work if `run-hooks` is called from C instaead of lisp. Furthermore, there are other functions like `run-hook-with-args-until-success`.

Comment: Upvoted for being informative, but agreeing with "don't do this".

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative write-up and sample code -- greatly appreciated!